# Workflow in progress even after Go to End of Workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow

I am using a workflow called Quick Checkout to edit items in a list. It successfully updates fields, but under Workflow Settings, it says it is still in progress. Should I worry about this? I have set the workflow to Go to End of Workflow:

[image: Simple workflow]

[image: Workflow settings page]

Answer (score 3):

Remove the step

```
set workflow status as Finished
```

Also instead of `Update in current item` use step `Set field in current item`.

SharePoint automatically updates the status as part of internal steps. User need not set the workflow status. As the end status is not "Finished" your workflow is in pending status.

Comment: The first part seems to solve the issue, but I am using `Update in current item` to set multiple fields at once. Is it still better to use `Set field in current item` when I have multiple things I am changing? Also, is there some way to manually end all workflows in progress? Thanks!

Comment: Update: removing `set workflow status as Finished` works on my Quick Checkout, but on the equivalent (but opposite) Quick Return, it does not help. New Workflows in Progress are still being added...

Comment: `Update in item` is used to update items for another list. For updating in same item, always used `Set field in current item`.

Comment: For Quick Return, can you send the workflow screenshot.

Comment: That is good to know about `Update in item` vs `Set field in current item`, thank you. I actually went a different route and linked to a page which did the Quick Checkouts and Returns via JavaScript. That way, I can display feedback to the user immediately if their action was valid, invalid, successful, unsuccessful, etc. Thanks for your help though, I understand workflows better now!